# Stop scan splitting my match

Tags: ruby, regex

When I scan for `zan` I get the entire group in one entry, behavior I expect and want:

```
"ax zan".scan /(zan)/ #=> [["zan"]]
```

How can I have the whole match returned, white space and all ? i.e

```
"ax       b".scan /.../ #=> [["ax       b"]]
```

When I scan for `(ax)\s*(b)`, the match is split into two entries:

```
"ax b".scan /(ax)\s*(b)/ #=> [["ax", "b"]]
```

**Update**

How do I use the `|` operator without groups?

```
"sab   x".scan /sab|p\s*x/ #=> [["sab   x"]]
"sap   x".scan /sab|p\s*x/ #=> [["sap   x"]]
```

Comment: Will there be multiple matches in your string? If not, you should use `match`, not `scan`.

Comment: @Jordan thanks, I'll bear that in mind for multiple matches

Comment: `"cax       bd"[/ax\s*b/] #=> "ax       b"`, `"cax       bd".scan /ax\s*b/ #=> ["ax       b"]` or `"cax       bd".scan /(ax\s*b)/ #=> [["ax       b"]]`, depending on your requirements.

Comment: You need a capture or non-capture group for `|`; e.g., `r = /sa(?:b|p)\s*x/; "csab  xd"[r] #=> "sab x"`. Here, though, you should be using a character class instead: `r = /sa[bp]\s*x/; "csap  xd"[r] #=> "sap  x"`. 
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, when you use a RegExp with groups, `String#scan` will return an array of arrays, the inner arrays each having one element for each capture. If that's not what you want, then you have to make your groups *non-capturing* by using the `?:` flag, e.g. `(?:foo|bar)`.

```ruby
expr = /sa(?:b|p)\s*x/
"sab   x".scan(expr) #=> ["sab   x"]
"sap   x".scan(expr) #=> ["sap   x"]
```

P.S. The above works, but since only one character differs, in this case you should use a character class instead:

```ruby
/sa[bp]\s*x/
```

P.P.S. You should only use `scan` if you're looking for multiple matches. If you just want one match, use `String#slice`, which has the handy `String#[]` alias. This will return the match as a string instead of an array:

```ruby
expr = /sa(?:b|p)\s*x/
"sab   x"[expr] #=> "sab   x"
"sap   x"[expr] #=> "sap   x"
```

In case it's not clear, this works on variables, too, like any other method:

```ruby
str = "sab   x"
str[/sa[bp]\s*x/] #=> "sab   x"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the capturing groups.

```
"ax       b".scan(/ax\s*b/)
```

To get the element inside another array, then put the above regex inside a capturing group.

```
"ax       b".scan(/(ax\s*b)/)
```

> `"ax b".scan /(ax)\s*(b)/ #=> [["ax", "b"]]` , i got two results why?

Because scan by default gives the first preference to groups . If no groups are present then it consider the matches. In the above, capturing groups are present in your regex which captures `ax`, `b` so you got these two elements within an array. Note that if you have any single capturing group present, the output format must be a two dimensional array.

**Example:**

```
irb(main):001:0> "ax       b".scan(/ax\s*b/)
=> ["ax       b"]
irb(main):002:0> "ax       b".scan(/(ax\s*b)/)
=> [["ax       b"]]
```

Comment: You could also use the expression `/((ax)\s*(b))/` if you want the groups *and* the whole match. It would return `[["ax  b", "ax", "b"]]`.

Comment: Updated, how do I use the or operator without groups?

Comment: oh... that actually sucks :/

Comment: At first op's regex is `sa|x`. That's why I posted the above comment.